# UIScrollView Content Insets not working for Keyboard Height

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am trying to move a `UIScrollView` when the keyboard hides a `UITextField` by changing the size using the `contentInsets` as it is shown.

However, it's not working for the keyboard height. The keyboard height comes as 216, but it only stops scrolling at the correct location if I set the bottom inset to 515 for iPhone portrait mode and 310 for iPhone landscape mode. Why would these dimensions be so different? I don't want to hardcode these arbitrary values in.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.frame = self.parentViewController.view.frame;

    [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];

    NSLog(@"scrollview: %f,%f, parent: %f,%f", self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.parentViewController.view.frame.size.height, self.parentViewController.view.frame.size.width);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

        // Step 1: Get the size of the keyboard.
        CGFloat keyboardHeight = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;

        // Step 2: Adjust the bottom content inset of your scroll view by the keyboard height.
        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0);
        ((UIScrollView*)self.view).contentInset = contentInsets;
        ((UIScrollView*)self.view).scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

        // Step 3: Scroll the target text field into view.
        CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
        aRect.size.height = aRect.size.height - keyboardHeight;
        if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.textView.frame.origin) ) {
            CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, self.textView.frame.origin.y - keyboardHeight);
            [((UIScrollView*)self.view) setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
        }
    }
}

- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    ((UIScrollView*)self.view).contentInset = contentInsets;
    ((UIScrollView*)self.view).scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Edit:

Before the keyboard is open, i print this out:

```
NSLog(@"scrollview: %f,%f, parent: %f,%f", self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.parentViewController.view.frame.size.height, self.parentViewController.view.frame.size.width);
```

and it prints this:

```
scrollview: 431.000000,320.000000, parent: 431.000000,320.000000
```

Comment: is is scrolling fine without keyboard, it might be possible you have given height greater than the height of parent view.

Comment: Yep. It's scrolling fine

Comment: i want to know the frame of scrollview and its parent view frame before opening the keyboard.

Comment: The UIScrollView is inside a UITabBarController. Please see my edits.

Comment: in your code is self.view is kind of scrollview?

Comment: Yes. [self.view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]; returns YES

Comment: can you share the code, because from here everything seems to be fine.

Comment: I've added all relevant code from the ViewController.

Comment: write these two lines self.view.frame = self.parentViewController.view.frame;
[self.textView becomeFirstResponder];in viewDidAppear instead of ViewDidLoad

Comment: That didn't seem to work.

Comment: Kristin take a look at `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize` property. If `contentSize.height` is not big enough, changing `contentInsets` alone might not be enough. That is, adding / removing the keyboard's height to the scrollview's `contentSize.height`

Comment: I added sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(sv.contentSize.width, sv.contentSize.height - keyboardHeight); (where sv is the uiscrollview) and it still didn't work :(

Comment: I also have issues with UIScrollView and content insets and I figured out that it is related to auto layout. If I disable auto layout in the xib-file, the problem disappears. I don't know more at this time, but maybe it helps you find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think that the main issue is that you need to use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead of `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`.

That being said, I have written a different version of this method that will work even if the scrollview is not placed at the bottom of the screen and may work better for you:

Note that I use `self.activeTextField` instead of `self.textField`.

```
// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    // Calculate the frame of the scrollview, in self.view's coordinate system
    UIScrollView *scrollView    = self.scrollView;
    CGRect scrollViewRect       = [self.view convertRect:scrollView.frame fromView:scrollView.superview];

    // Calculate the frame of the keyboard, in self.view's coordinate system
    NSDictionary* info          = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGRect kbRect               = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    kbRect                      = [self.view convertRect:kbRect fromView:nil];

    // Figure out where the two frames overlap, and set the content offset of the scrollview appropriately
    CGRect hiddenScrollViewRect = CGRectIntersection(scrollViewRect, kbRect);
    if (!CGRectIsNull(hiddenScrollViewRect))
    {
        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets       = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0,  0.0, hiddenScrollViewRect.size.height,  0.0);
        scrollView.contentInset          = contentInsets;
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    }

    [self scrollToActiveTextField];
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    self.scrollView.contentInset          = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}

- (void)scrollToActiveTextField
{
    if (self.activeTextField)
    {
        CGRect visibleRect = self.activeTextField.frame;
        visibleRect        = [self.scrollView convertRect:visibleRect fromView:self.activeTextField.superview];
        visibleRect        = CGRectInset(visibleRect, 0.0f, -5.0f);
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:visibleRect animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Previously I was trying to manipulate the scrollview's frame to achieve this but using `contentInset` made the code much simpler.

Comment: If you are tearing your hair out trying to figure out why scrollRectToVisible isn't working, Apple seems to have changed something (at least with iOS 8 in my simulator) where if the rect is outside the UITableView, UICollectionView or UIScrollView content frame, it doesn't even bother trying to scroll to it.  For example, I had called [self.activeField convertRect:self.activeField.frame toView:self.tableView] but it should have been [self.activeField.superview convertRect:self.activeField.frame toView:self.tableView], so the rect.origin.x was at like 500, which is > 320 so it wouldn't scroll.

Comment: This is one of the greatest answers of all time. This is a common issue, but searching for things like "keyboard hides UITextField" in Google fail to surface this answer.

Answer (score 0):

set delegate of your scrollView as self whereever you are crating scrollview in your code

```
 ((UIScrollView*)self.view).delegate=self;
```

then

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.frame = self.parentViewController.view.frame;

    [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];

    NSLog(@"scrollview: %f,%f, parent: %f,%f", self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.parentViewController.view.frame.size.height, self.parentViewController.view.frame.size.width);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

        // Step 1: Get the size of the keyboard.
        CGFloat keyboardHeight = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;

        // Step 2: Adjust the bottom content inset of your scroll view by the keyboard height.
        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0);
        ((UIScrollView*)self.view).contentInset = contentInsets;
        ((UIScrollView*)self.view).scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

        ((UIScrollView*)self.view).scrollEnabled=YES;
    }
}

- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    ((UIScrollView*)self.view).contentInset = contentInsets;
    ((UIScrollView*)self.view).scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    [((UIScrollView*)self.view) setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f) animated:TRUE];
    ((UIScrollView*)self.view).contentSize = CGSizeMake(((UIScrollView*)self.view).contentSize.width, ((UIScrollView*)self.view).contentSize.height);
    ((UIScrollView*)self.view).scrollEnabled=NO;

}

#pragma mark - set scrollView content position
-(void)scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:(UIView *)theView
{
    CGFloat theViewY = theView.center.y;
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    CGFloat avaliableHeight = applicationFrame.size.height - 300;
    CGFloat y = theViewY - avaliableHeight / 2.0;
    if(y<0)
        y = 0;
    [((UIScrollView*)self.view) setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,y) animated:YES];
}

#pragma -mark UITextField Delegate methods

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:textField];
    return YES;
}
```

Now set delegate of your text field. Whenever textFieldShouldBeginEditing: your scrollview automatically move on that. scrollViewToCenterOfScreen: method set your scrollview position at textfiled position.

It definitely set your scrollview content insets as well as setContentOffset. Please let me know if you still facing this problem. Thanks

Comment: Hi Chandan, the issue isn't that it's not setting the insets - i can set them manually. The issue is that I can't figure out the correct height to set them at from any other elements on the screen. I'm using an arbitrary number for height.

Comment: Hi Kristin. Sorry for late reply. Have you resolved your problem? Please let me know so i can clarify about it. Thanks

Comment: I have not - we're still hardcoding it

Comment: Hi Kristin,  let me try it and then i'll give you a correct answer

Comment: Hi kristin i have again updated my code a give you better solution to set scroll position and setContentOffset dynamically